# Question about theorem on homotopic curves for a holomorphic function (Stein and Shakarchi)

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem, is about the integral over two homotopic curves for a holomorphic function being equal in Stein and Shakarchi.:
[image: page1]

I don't understand the argument presented in the first paragraph for this proof:
[image: page2]
[image: page3]
I can see that the first few sentences is trying to establish openness for the image of f. I don't understand the argument after - "if not..." upto the end of the paragraph. What is he trying to establish?

Answer (score 1):

They are proving that, for some $\varepsilon>0$, every disk with radius $3\varepsilon$ centered at a point of $F\bigl([0,1]\times[a,b]\bigr)$ is a subset of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book, but I assume the idea of the proof will be something similar to the following: Look at the picture you provided. It's a drawing of the image of $F(s,t)$, where the lines drawn correspond to constant $s$. You could now add more lines corresponding to constant $t$ to get something looking like a net covering the image of $F$. The idea is to show that you can make the net fine enough to allow each "hole" in the net to be contained in a disc of radius $\varepsilon$, which in turn is contained in $\Omega$. Then you can apply Cauchy's integral theorem to the integral along the boundary of a single hole, and then add the integrals along the boundaries of every hole to get the integral along the boundary of the entire net, which will then be $0$, so the integrals along $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ will be the same.

To actually use this idea, though, they first need to establish that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ small enough that such discs centered at points in the image of $F$ actually are contained in $\Omega$. That's what they're doing. Using $3\varepsilon$ instead of $\varepsilon$ is probably so that they can use a triangle inequality in some way to get discs of radius $\varepsilon$ in the end. But right now, they're trying to show that there is some radius ($3\varepsilon$) such that every disc with that radius whose center lies in $K$ is contained in $\Omega$. Essentially, there is a minimum distance between the boundaries of $K$ and $\Omega$ greater than $0$.

Comment: Thank you @Vercassivelaunos! That is very helpful. I would imagine that if there are two overlapping discs, their centers are at a distance of $\epsilon$ then we need to take $3 \epsilon$ for two discs! In the argument, he says we must have $w_{l_k} \to z$ - is it because $|w_{l} -z_{l}|< 1/l$ as well? so since $z_{l} \to z$, $w_{l} \to z$ as well?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason.